# Raylib in C gives 'undefined function' error on compile

Tags: c, raylib

I'm trying to remake Pong from scratch using C. I've built the game and now I want to actually see it. I'm using Windows 10 with VSCode (most likely the issue).

My tasks.json command:

```
"args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-std=c99",
                "-I\"D:\\forrk\\C Game\\raylib-5.0_win64_mingw-w64\\include\"",
                "-L\"D:\\forrk\\C Game\\raylib-5.0_win64_mingw-w64\\lib\"",
                "-lraylib",
                "-o2",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
            ],
```

Compiler:
`gcc --version`
gcc.exe (Rev2, Built by MSYS2 project) 13.2.0
Copyright (C) 2023 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

This is the error message I'm getting every time (yes I have it in Spanish, "compilar archivo activo" means "compile active file", "Iniciando la compilación" means "Beginning compilation", "La compilación ha finalizado con errores" means "Compilation finished with errors"):

```
Executing task: C/C++: gcc.exe compilar archivo activo 

Iniciando la compilación...
D:\forrk\_tool\ucrt64\bin\gcc.exe -fdiagnostics-color=always -g "D:\forrk\C Game\pong.c" -std=c99 -I"D:\forrk\C Game\raylib-5.0_win64_mingw-w64\include" -L"D:\forrk\C Game\raylib-5.0_win64_mingw-w64\lib" -lraylib -o2 -o "D:\forrk\C Game\pong.exe"
D:/forrk/_tool/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: D:\forrk\C Game\raylib-5.0_win64_mingw-w64\lib/libraylib.a(rcore.o):rcore.c:(.text+0x1c494): undefined reference to `timeEndPeriod'

La compilación ha finalizado con errores.

 *  The terminal process failed to launch (exit code: -1). 
 *  Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.
```

I installed raylib in the following manners:
1- Putting everything in the project folder: IntelliSense finds it but tasks.json didn't.
2- Fixed tasks.json and moved the 'include' and 'lib' folders outside their original folder: No errors or warning when using #include, but still won't compile.
3- Moving 'lib' to its own folder in C: (as suggested by other posts): no effect

Is this a VSCode issue? Am I doing something wrong? I got my version off raylib.com -> github, also tried cloning with git directly just to get the same results.

Ideally I want to use VSCode for C and not need to touch anything on Visual Studio (which I have set up for C# and Unity)

Comment: It should be `"-O2"`, not `"-o2"`.

Comment: Note that `-o2` is not the same as `-O2`. Options are case-sensitive.

Comment: Sidenote: c99 is pretty old. Your compiler will most probably support c17 too.

Comment: It is not appropriate here to modify question titles to indicate that the question has been solved, nor to edit the question to thank for or remark about the speed of answers.  If you are so inclined (and apparently you were) "accept" one of the answers by clicking on the checkmark next to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`timeEndPeriod`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/timeapi/nf-timeapi-timeendperiod) function is defined in the `winmm` library so you need to add `-lwinmm` to the set of linker options, after `-lraylib`.

Also note that it should be `-O2` (meaning optimization level 2), not `-o2` (meaning that the output file should be named `2`):

```json
"-lraylib",
"-lwinmm",
"-O2",
```

Answer (score 0):

To fix it, you have to add some more `-l...` options (in addition to `-lraylib`) to the `gcc` command (`args` within `tasks.json in your case).

Here is the relevant error message:

```
D:/forrk/_tool/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: D:\forrk\C Game\raylib-5.0_win64_mingw-w64\lib/libraylib.a(rcore.o):rcore.c:(.text+0x1c494): undefined reference to `timeEndPeriod'
```

The functions within `libraylib.a` (see full path in the error message) are already added by the `-lraylib` option. In fact, `-lX` adds `D:\forrk\C Game\raylib-5.0_win64_mingw-w64\lib\libX.a` a in this case (with `X` being `raylib`). Do a search for `timeEndPeriod` within `D:\forrk\C Game\raylib-5.0_win64_mingw-w64\lib\lib*.a`, and for each filename found, add the corresponding `-lX` option.

Alternatively, you may want to consult the *raylib* documentation on what it recommends in addition to `-lraylib`.